# how can convert LPCSTR string into LPCTSTR string?

Tags: string, casting, lpcstr

i am trying to convert a `LPCSTR` string into `LPCTSTR` string. i want to concatenate two string,when i try like this

```
LPCTSTR str1 = L"Raja"
LPCSTR str2 = "Kumar"
wcscat_s(str1,(LPCTSTR)str2);
```

i found the o/p like Raja....r(junkvalues)....how can typecast `LPCSTR` to `LPCTSTR`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LPCTSTR` can be either plain char or wide characters depending on your project settings. Further, you cannot possibly concatenate a wide string and a plain char string. You need to convert one to a compatible form (wide to multibyte or vice versa) and then concatenate.

Assuming you want the target to be a wide string, you'd need to convert the `"Kumar"` to a wide character string. To do this use the [`MultiByteToWideChar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms886760.aspx) function with appropriate code page.

Look up [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/138813) KB article on MSDN and John's link.

Answer (score 0):

MultiByteToWideChar is the only way to go, if your code is compiled with UNICODE.

Alternatively you can do this. 7bits ASCII -> wchar should be easy.

```
TCHAR str3[256] = { 0 };
for (int i = 0; str2[i] != 0; i++) str3[i] = str2[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this it worked:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <atlstr.h>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    LPCSTR stringToConvert = "My troublesome string";
    CString transitionString = stringToConvert;
    LPCTSTR myDesiredString = transitionString;

    wcout  << myDesiredString;
}
```